# Dynamic Programming: Calculate all possible end positions for a list of consecutive jumps

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

The problem consists in calculate all possible end positions and how many combinations exist for each one.

Given a start position `x=0`, a length `m` of the track and a list of jumps. Return the number of possible ends for each position on the interval [-m/2,+m/2]. The jumps must be done in the same order as given but it could be done in negative or positive way.

For example:

```
L = 40
jumps = 10, 10
```

Solution:

```
-20 : 1  (-10, -10)
0 : 2 (-10,+10 & +10,-10)
20 : 1 (+10,+10)
```

(The output needed is only the pair "position : #combinations")

I did it with a simple recursion, and the result is OK.
But in large sets of data, the execution time is few minutes or hours.
I know that with dynamic programming I can have a solution in few seconds, but I don't know how can I apply dynamic in this case.

There's my actual recursive function:

```
void escriuPosibilitats(queue<int> q, map<int,int> &res, int posicio, int m) {
    int salt = q.front();
    q.pop();
    if(esSaltValid(m,posicio,-salt)) {
        int novaPosicio = posicio - salt;
        if(q.empty()) {
            res[novaPosicio]++;
        } else {
            escriuPosibilitats(q,res,novaPosicio,m);
        }
    }
    if(esSaltValid(m,posicio,salt)) {
        int novaPosicio = posicio + salt;
        if(q.empty()) {
            res[novaPosicio]++;
        } else {
            escriuPosibilitats(q,res,novaPosicio,m);
        }
    }
}
```

1. Where `q` is the queue of the remaining jumps.
2. Where `res` is the parcial solution.
3. Where `posicio` is the actual position.
4. Where `m` is the length of the track.
5. Where `esSaltValid` is a function that checks if the jump is valid in the range of the track length.

PD: Sorry for my english level. I tried to improve my question! Thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following idea. Let dp[x][i] be the number of ways to arrive to the position x using until the jump i. Then the answer would be dp[x][N] for each x, and where N is the number of jumps. Even more, you can realize that this dp depends only on the previous row, and then you can simply dp[x] and save the next row in some auxiliary array, and then replace it in each iteration. The code would be something like this:

```
const int MOD = (int)(1e8+7);
    const int L = 100;
    int N = 36;
    int dx[] = {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1};

    int dp[L+1];
    int next[L+1];

    int main() {
      int shift = L/2; // to handle negative indexes
      dp[shift] = 1; // the initial position has one way to arrive, since you start there
      for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) { // for each jump size
        for (int x = -L/2; x <= L/2; ++x) { // for each possible position
          if (-L/2 <= x + dx[i] && x + dx[i] <= L/2) // positive jump
            next[x + shift] = (next[x + shift] + dp[x + dx[i] + shift]) % MOD;
          if (-L/2 <= x - dx[i] && x - dx[i] <= L/2) // negative jump
            next[x + shift] = (next[x + shift] + dp[x - dx[i] + shift]) % MOD;
        }
        for (int x = -L/2; x <= L/2; ++x) { // update current dp to next and clear next
          dp[x+shift] = next[x+shift];
          next[x+shift] = 0;
        }
      }
      for (int x = -L/2; x <= L/2; ++x) // print the result
        if (dp[x+shift] != 0) {
          cout << x << ": " << dp[x+shift] << '\n';  
        }
    }
```

Of course, in case L is too big to handle, you can compress the state space and save the results in a map, and not in an array. The complexity of the approach is O(L*N). Hope it helped.

**EDIT**: just compute everything modulo 1e8+7 and that's it.

Comment: It's incorrect in some cases.
For example in:

    L = 100
    N = 36
    dx = {1s}

Comment: For example in: L = 100 N = 36 dx = {1s}
It return negative results and wrong numbers

Comment: Supposing "1s" means that dx is an array of 36 ones in this case, then the negative numbers are because the result is too big to fit in 32 bit integers. Change the type to long long.

Comment: @user1782922 which value exactly is wrong? They look ok to me.

Comment: For example for: -16  returns 254186856  and the correct answer is 54186842

Comment: Maybe you're not invalidating the sum of wrong tracks?

Comment: how do you know that is the correct value indeed? How did you compute it? And what do you mean by "wrong tracks"?

Comment: Because I have some tests with the expected answer

Comment: I mean the cases when a path is outgoing the track. It's enough with the ifs?

Comment: Is this a problem from some programming contest or some online judge? Can you provide such tests or the original statement of the problem? Usually such problems ask to write the answer modulo some big prime number.

Comment: I must print the solution (mod) 10^8+7 jajaja

I forgot to say it! :( :(

Comment: Finally I do the mod when you update current dp to next and clear next to copy

Comment: @user1782922 I edited the answer with the mod computation. Good luck.

Comment: I have a list of exercises to do and I've solved many but I  couldn't see how to apply DP in this one.
You solve my life!! Thanks =)